# Excel Comparing List 2(current) against List 1(Existing) for duplicates and new items

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Existing    Current    Duplicates   New
------------------------------------------
apple       banana     banana       plum
orange      plum       grapes       mango
banana      grapes
strawberry  mango    
grapes
```

Any suggestion to get the "duplicate" and "new" based on the "current" list?

Comment: Welcome over at SO, however "*I need..."* type-questions are off-topic. Probably different to some other forums out there, SO requires a much more detailed question about issues related to coding/formulae. Please refer to [ask] a question with a [mcve] and check just how much [effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/9758194) is required from your end before even posting.

Answer (score 1):

I admit that my solution is not working, but you might be helped with the general idea:

I started with two formulas:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A$6,B2)>0,B2,"")
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A$6,B2)=0,B2,"")
```

As you see, I used `COUNTIF()` to see how many times an item from column B appears in column A, and based on that I did two things:

```
- If the item appears at least one time, it is shown, else an empty string is shown.
- If the itema appears not at all, it is shown, else an empty string is shown.
```

Like that, you get two columns with the values you're looking for.

Then it was my idea to "sort" them, by taking the first entry, then the second, then the third, ..., using the `LARGE()` function, but that seems not to work (`LARGE()` only seems to work on numbers). If you would find a way to get the largest, then the second largest, ... from an array of strings, you might find a solution.

Comment: Sir, everything is helpful, whether its working or not, we learn from everything thank you for the whole explanation, It helped me at least to know something

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 solution:

`=FILTER(B2:B5,COUNTIF(A2:A6,B2:B5))`
`=FILTER(B2:B5,COUNTIF(A2:A6,B2:B5)=0)`

Older Excel:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$5)/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,$B$2:$B$5),ROW(1:1))),"")` in `C2` copied down.
`=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$5)/(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$6,$B$2:$B$5)=0),ROW(1:1))),"")` in `D2` copied down.

Comment: `FILTER()` function is the easiest one i believe. Sir, you could have shown this with one formula, which is your specialty in using `LET()` --> `=LET(A,A2:A6,B,B2:B5,CHOOSE({1,2},FILTER(B,COUNTIF(A,B)),FILTER(B,COUNTIF(A,B)=0)))`

Comment: Or, may be with only `CHOOSE()` --> `=CHOOSE({1,2},FILTER(B2:B5,COUNTIF(A2:A6,B2:B5)),FILTER(B2:B5,COUNTIF(A2:A6,B2:B5)=0))` sir your response is much expected. because if there is something wrong then i shall learn from you

Comment: Sir, check this one, with `HSTACK()` --> `=HSTACK(FILTER(B2:B5,COUNTIF(A2:A6,B2:B5)),FILTER(B2:B5,COUNTIF(A2:A6,B2:B5)=0))`

Comment: Sir, I hope you don't mind, just sharing all the alternatives in one place, --> `=LET(A,A2:A6,B,B2:B5,C,COUNTIF(A,B),D,FILTER(B,C),E,FILTER(B,C=0),HSTACK(D,E))`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the alternatives. I can't wait to get access to HSTACK/VSTACK.

Comment: I hope you like it :)

Comment: I like the LET version to get it at once, but that's because they're most familiar to me.

Comment: Yes really `LET()` make readability very clear.